# Apache POI modify chart without using named ranges

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openoffice-calc

I need to present data from my db into an .xls spreadsheet.
I can read/write to the xls file without any issue, but obviously I cannot create the chart from scratch.

I read every documentation I could find and created a template file with the chart in Excel to be modified by POI.

The problem I'm facing is the following: I was able to create named ranges, assign them to my chart and modify them through POI, no problem at all. When I reverted to OpenOffice Calc problems started: it has no support for named ranges as data sources for charts, so:

is there any way to update charts data WITHOUT using named ranges (I can give the chart the range myself, every serie is a delimited part of a row)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using named ranges is the easiest way to change the chart data based on an unknown amount of data to place in the chart.

If the number of rows in the data is constant, then you can assign the constant range of data to the chart.

If the number of rows is unknown beforehand, then it gets trickier without named ranges.  The key here is the use of Excel's `OFFSET` and `COUNTA` formulas in the chart of the template sheet.

[This article](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=518) describes the use of these formulas to create a dynamic range based on the content of the data.

The `COUNTA` formula counts how many cells in a constant range are filled.  The `OFFSET` formula creates a dynamic range based on its inputs, which include column and row parameters for the start of the range, and length and width parameters for how big the dynamic range needs to be.

For example, if you have a header row in row 1, you have 5 fields of data (columns A-E) and you know that column A in your data will never be blank or empty, e.g.

```
First Name | Last Name | Hire Date | Salary | Manager
-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------
Data       | Goes      | Here      |        |
```

... then use something like the following formula in your chart range to determine the dynamic range:

```
=OFFSET(A2, 0, 0, COUNTA(A2:A101), 5)
```

This means: Start with A2.  Adjust the start of the range with an offset of 0 rows and 0 columns (top left of your range is A2).  The height of the range is the number of rows that are filled in between A2 and A101 (assuming your data is a max of 100 rows; adjust the `A101` constant based on your needs).  The width of the range is 5 columns.

The article linked above describes it in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but I think I need something more specific to my question. I wrote I cannot use named ranges for my chart because OpenOffice Calc doesn't support them, so I'm asking for any way to create a chart editable via POI and visible using Calc and Excel. Can I assign the function =OFFSET(xxxxxxxx) to a chart without using named ranges in Calc? Can I modify it afterwards using POI? Thank you!